# Reverse pretty date format

Tags: python, datetime, date

Is there a way to go from

`"1 day ago", "1 week ago", "3 hours ago"`

to some date format like "Tue, 19 Jul 2011 10:00:00" using Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chronic (Ruby NLP date/time parser) for python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719088/chronic-ruby-nlp-date-time-parser-for-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719088/chronic-ruby-nlp-date-time-parser-for-python) suggests http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/deltaTime.py) on the pyparsing wiki supports these cases:

```
today
tomorrow
yesterday
in a couple of days
a couple of days from now
a couple of days from today
in a day
3 days ago
3 days from now
a day ago
in 2 weeks
in 3 days at 5pm
now
10 minutes ago
10 minutes from now
in 10 minutes
in a minute
in a couple of minutes
20 seconds ago
in 30 seconds
20 seconds before noon
20 seconds before noon tomorrow
noon
midnight
noon tomorrow
6am tomorrow
0800 yesterday
12:15 AM today
3pm 2 days from today
a week from today
a week from now
3 weeks ago
noon next Sunday
noon Sunday
noon last Sunday
2pm next Sunday
next Sunday at 2pm
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there are libraries available (if there are, I'm sure they can be found in Django source code - it sounds like the kind of problems they must have thought of).

However, I don't find the problem too difficult in principle. You first define your boundaries. For example:

- If it happened within one day, I'll spell out the hour
- If it happened within six days, I'll spell out the number of days
- If it happened within four weeks, I'll spell out the number of weeks
- [etc]

Then you use the `datetime` module (specifically the `timedelta` object) and filter out your desires according to the duration. A basic version should be up an running in less than an hour.

Again - I encourage you to look for implemented solutions, but if you cannot figure out a basic way to get this working, I'm afraid your Python skills may be lacking and you may want to practice by reinventing the wheel.