# Natural language time parser

Tags: python, parsing, time, nlp

I'm trying to parse strings containing (natural language) times to *hh:mm* time objects? For example:

```
"ten past five"
"quarter to three"
"half past noon"
"15 past 3"
"13:35"
"ten fourteen am"
```

I've looked into [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) for Ruby and [Natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/) for Java (as well as some other libraries) but both seem to focus on parsing dates. Strings like "ten past five" are not parsed correctly by either.

Does anyone know of a library which suit my needs? Or should I maybe start working on my own parser?

Comment: This one seems beautiful, and supports many languages: https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't feel like extending parsedatetime, so I decided to use [pyPEG](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/index.html), a parser interpreter framework for Python, to write a dedicated time parser. For whoever's interested, the [first basic version](https://gist.github.com/3054114) is now finished, and nicely parses Dutch time strings.

Comment: Just for anyone who is interested, I found this: [https://gist.github.com/akatzbreaker/5849024](https://gist.github.com/akatzbreaker/5849024) This is the **same** as Bert's Anwser on Github, but it is in English... **Just for anyone who is interested on this, and doesn't know Dutch :-P ...**

Answer (score 10):

[`parsedatetime`](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) looks promising. [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/719197/1291812).

Comment: parsedatetime does some of the things I need, but it does not seem to parse strings like "ten past five", "quarter to three", "half past noon"...

Comment: Alas, that was all some searching returned... You may want to add to that plugin or write a wrapper function with custom logic for those cases if you can't find any other plugin.